# PHP session files unable to save after a mass deletion

Tags: php5, session

I had an excess of php sessions files created on a server in `/var/lib/php5/` so I deleted them, but now php5-fpm and my server refuse to write sessions files.

I assumed that the session files would be able to be recreated, but now the application does not retain session data at all, apparently.  What do I do to start the session directory anew?

Comment: Exactly what did you delete? What are the errors that are logged?

Comment: Is there anything in error logs? Did you delete just content of dir or whole dir? Did you tried to restart php5-fpm service?

Comment: If you deleted the directory, chances are your webserver doesn't have permissions to create it again.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yep, turned out that I hadn't just deleted the session files, I had stupidly deleted the whole directory, and of course it was thus unable to recreate sessions, and even when I recreated the directory, it had to be world writable.  Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was a permissions issue with the directory:

```
php -i | grep session.save_path
session.save_path => /var/lib/php5/sessions => /var/lib/php5/sessions
```

And that directory had to have the correct write permissions:

```
sudo ls ../ -halt
total 52K
drwx-wx-wt  2 root root  36K Oct 29 17:21 sessions
```

I had accidentally made it not world-writable (and maybe not sticky) when I recreated it.